# The Yang-Mills Higgs Lagrangian

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-topology, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

Let's say we have a principal bundle $(P,B,\pi;G)$ and associated bundle $E=P \times_{(G,\rho)}V$and $Ad(P)=P\times_{(G,Ad)} \mathfrak{g}$ the adjoint bundle. The Yang-Mills-Higgs action (without potential) is

\begin{equation}
\int_M(- \frac{1}{2}\langle F^A, F^A \rangle_{\operatorname{Ad}(P)} +\langle d_A \phi, d_A \phi \rangle_E - m^2 \langle \phi, \phi \rangle_E )d\nu_g
\end{equation}
with $\phi \in \Gamma(E)$. If we vary the equation, i.e. add $A+t \omega$ and $\phi+t \alpha$ and then take $d/dt$ the equations of motion are

\begin{equation}
\delta_A F^A=j \quad \delta_A d_A \phi=0
\end{equation}
with the codifferential $\delta_A$ and the implicit defined current

\begin{equation}
\langle j, \alpha \rangle = -\langle d_A \phi,\rho_*(\alpha) \phi \rangle
\end{equation}
In Differential Geometry And Mathematical Physics 2 by Gerd Rudolph and Matthias Schmidt it says that if we take the associated bundle, i.e. $E$ to be the adjoint bundle, the first equation of motion becomes

\begin{equation}
\delta_A F^A=[d_A \phi,\phi]
\end{equation}

I have two equations:

1. How can I derive $j=[d_A \phi,\phi]$ form the general equation for the current. And how do I express it in local coordinates to get something similar to the currents in physics.
2. Is there some Binachi-identity for the curvature form with the codifferential, i.e. $\delta_A \delta_A F^A=0$. This somehow should be the case, since the current should be conserved, i.e. $\delta_A j=0$

Comment: Who are the authors of the textbook in question?

Comment: Sorry, I included the names of the author in my question

Comment: One can show something like ${\text{d}_A}^2=F^A\wedge(\cdot)$, so your "Bianchi identity" reads $0=\delta_A\delta_AF^A=*\text{d}_A\text{d}_A*F^A=*(F^A\wedge *F^A)$ and since $*$ is an iso you know that $F^A\wedge *F^A=0$, and the dynamic Lagrangian of $A$ vanishes. I don't think this is true. Are you sure that $j$ should be conserved w.r.t $\delta_A$?

Comment: @nicrot000 At least in Bleeckers book gauge theory and variational principles $\delta^{\omega}j=0$ is written down. But probably the current is defined in another way.

Comment: I don't know that reference. But i looked that up, on any associated bundle $E$ of $P$ you can define a wedge of $\text{Ad}(P)$- and of $E$-valued forms, and $\text{d}_A^2$ in $E$ is just this wedge product with $F^A\in\Omega^2(M;\text{Ad}(P))$. So if $E=\text{Ad}(P)$, then this wedge product should be the same as the one you write the Yang-Mills Lagrangian with. Hence, the identity $\delta_A^2F^A$ should render this Lagrangian, which is what I wrote above up to taking the trace, trivial.

Comment: Or I'm doing something wrong... I'm also waiting for some more sophisticated answer to your question than mine...

Comment: I think your are right in some sense. Since for general gauge theories the local and global gauge group are not the same, Noether's first theorem does not apply and one need Noether's second theorem. But I have not figured out the details, how this influences the current

Comment: For what it’s worth, 1 follows from invariance and nondegeneracy of the Killing form.

Comment: For the adjoint bundle , $\rho_*=ad(\cdot)(\cdot)=[\cdot,\cdot]$. Hence $\langle j, \alpha\rangle=-\left\langle d_{A} \phi, [\alpha, \phi ]\right\rangle$. Because of ad-invariance, the commutator can be 'moved': $\langle j, \alpha\rangle=-\left\langle [d_{A} \phi, \phi],  \alpha \right\rangle$. Is this right?. The rest its then just non degeneracy.

Comment: That's the calculation.

Comment: Thanks. But in local coordinates, if $\phi$ is complex valued, there is always a complex conjugation. How does this come into play

Comment: Not sure I really understand the question.

Comment: The current in local coordinates is $j_{\mu}=\mathrm{i}\left(\phi^{\dagger} D_{\mu} \phi-\left(D_{\mu} \phi^{\dagger}\right) \phi\right)$ with $D_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+\rho_*(A_{\mu})$. I don't get how I can derive it form $[d_A \phi, \phi]$. In local coordinates $d_A=[s(x),\nabla^A_{\partial_{\mu}}\phi]$ and $D_{\mu}=\nabla^A_{\partial_{\mu}}$. $\phi$ is in $\Gamma(E)$ but when we go into local coordinates on an open set $U$, it is just a function $U \rightarrow V$ with the vector space of the associated bundle. So for the adjoint bundle $V= \mathfrak{g}$

Comment: I'm not sure what your $s(x)$ is, but the covariant derivative in local coordinates should be the same as $d_A$. I suspect your $s(x)$ is supposed to be the local section, which will manifest as a gauge transformation of $A_\mu$, giving you the same answer.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. $s(x)$ is a local section. But how do I get the $\phi^{\dagger}$. I mean $[d_A \phi, \phi]=\sum_{a,b}D_{\mu}\phi^a \wedge \phi^b [T_a,T_b]$. E.g. for electromagnetism, this is just $\phi D_\mu \phi$. Or am I doing something wrong

Comment: I think you’ve complexified and extended the Killing form to a hermitian inner product, giving you the complex conjugation.

Comment: But in the expression $[d_A \phi, \phi]$ there is no Killing form involved?

Comment: Probably was written down for a real field.

Comment: But how exactly does the calculation change when we use a complex vector space as underlying space for $Ad(P)$. Where in the derivation do we explicitly use, that the underlying space is real.

Comment: Try redoing the calculation with the Hermitian inner product and see what you get.

Comment: I assume that $\left\langle d_{A} \phi,[\alpha, \phi]\right\rangle=\left\langle\left[d_{A} \phi, \phi\right], \alpha\right\rangle$ fails. But I am really stuck at this point

Comment: I think I found the problem. We do not require $\int_M \langle j, \alpha\rangle_{Ad(P)}= \int_m -\left\langle d_{A} \phi, \rho_{*}(\alpha) \phi\right\rangle_E$ to define $j$ but $\langle j, \alpha\rangle_{Ad(P)}=-\left\langle d_{A} \phi, \rho_{*}(\alpha) \phi\right\rangle_E$. But in general this can't be true because the left side could be complex. I.e. we need $\langle j, \alpha\rangle_{Ad(P)}=- Re(\left\langle d_{A} \phi, \rho_{*}(\alpha) \phi\right\rangle_E)$. But why can't we use the integral expression to define $j$?

Comment: Why not try sticking a complex conjugate in there and see what happens....

Comment: The left side is invariant. But the right side to, I think. $\int_{M}-\left\langle d_{A} \phi, \rho_{*}(\alpha) \phi\right\rangle_{E}=\int_{M}-\left\langle d_{A} \phi, \rho_{*}(\alpha) \phi\right\rangle_{E}^*$. Both are elements in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you maybe help me with one last problem. $Re [d_A \phi, \phi]=1/2 \cdot ((D_{\mu} \phi \phi-\phi D_{\mu} \phi)^*+(D_{\mu} \phi \phi-\phi D_{\mu} \phi)) $. But this is unequal $1/2\cdot(\phi^* D_{\mu} \phi+ \phi (D_{\mu}\phi)^*)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The first question has been already answered in a comment by NicAG, but let us repeat the 3-line long argument here for completeness:

> For the adjoint bundle , ρ∗=ad(⋅)(⋅)=[⋅,⋅]. Hence $⟨j,α⟩=−⟨d_Aϕ,[α,ϕ]⟩$. Because of ad-invariance, the commutator can be 'moved': $⟨j,α⟩=⟨[d_Aϕ,ϕ],α⟩$. The rest its then just non degeneracy.

**Edit:** changed the sign in the latter formula because so [does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form#Properties) 'moving' the commutator.

**Remark.** Possible confusion (see the comments) may come from another common formula for the current borrowed here from a different context:
$$j_μ=i(ϕ^†D_μϕ−(D_μϕ^†)ϕ).$$
In fact the latter formula is not applicable here because in the extremely abstract setting considered in the book, there is simply no complex structure, hence no complex conjugation. But if we come down to Earth and recall that G is a *compact* Lie group (this is assumed in the 3rd line of Section 7.2 `Yang–Mills–Higgs Systems' in the book in question), hence, ``more or less'', subset of $U(n)$, hence any element $\phi$ of the Lie algebra satisfies $ϕ^†=-ϕ$, then we come to the same expression (up to constant factor). Then, plugging in the expressions
$$
D_μϕ=(d_Aϕ)_\mu=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x^\mu}+A_\mu\phi-\phi A_\mu,
$$
one gets the expression for the current in local coordinates.

2. The identities $δ_Aj=0$ and $δ_Aδ_AF_A=0$  indeed hold with a one-line proof: for each element $\alpha$ of the Lie algebra we have
   $$
   \langle δ_Aδ_AF_A,\alpha\rangle=\langle F_A,d_Ad_A\alpha\rangle=\langle F_A,[\alpha,F_A]\rangle=\langle \alpha,[F_A,F_A]\rangle=0.
   $$
   However this is not called ``the Bianchi identity'', the name being already reserved for the identity $d_AF_A=0$ (Eq. 7.2.6 in the book in question).

**Remark.** One should not be confused (see the comments) by another common formula $d_Ad_A\phi=F\wedge \phi$, which is valid for a 'vector' $\phi$ but *not* for a 'matrix' $\phi$ (more formally, for the fundamental representation but not for the adjoint representation).

**Remark.** In fact the material of the book is not properly exposed in the question. For instance, in the right-hand side of the equation of motion $δ_Ad_Aϕ=0$ there should be $mϕ$ or $-mϕ$ instead. Notice that here the Higgs potential $V(\phi)=m^2|\phi|^2$ does *not* vanish. But in the absence of higher degree terms in the potential, the action should not be called Yang-Mills-Higgs action: it is rather action for a Klein-Gordon field coupled with a Yang-Mills field.

**Remark.** Maybe the deep source of all those confusions is an extremely abstract style of most literature on the subject. Let me try to advertise [a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.04788) with an elementary introduction of gauge theory. See Sections 2.4-2.5 there. It deals with a lattice formulation, thus to get a deep understanding, one even does not need to know what a derivative is.